# How do I require a date from a specific day of the week in my sharepoint form?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, date

I have a form I've created in Sharepoint where I need the requester to enter a date. This I've got set up. I would like to make this field so they have to enter a specific day of the week, in my case, Sunday. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: What version of sharepoint is this? Is the form a custom form? If yes how did you create the form

Answer (score 0):

You can set the column validation to only allow Sunday.
The formula is like this:`=IF(TEXT([Sunday Only],"dddd")="Sunday",TRUE,FALSE)`

Go List Settings>Select the column you want to only allow sunday

[image]